# Angular Service Not Called on first load

Tags: angular, service, request, local-storage

I am using Angular 9.0.7 on my current project. I have a backend written in Node.js (Express) with a frontend written in Angular.

The issue I encounter is that my service is not calling the function that handles the request to the backend to retrieve data on the first load, it does however work if I refresh the page.

I have a deviceService.ts file where I handle all the requests related to the devices. I have a Get Request to retrieve all the devices I have in the database. The authentication token is being loaded and I can see it, the device request is not going through on the initial load. The function of the deviceService.ts file looks like this:

```
  getAllDevices(){
    this.authenticationService.login(this.username, this.password);
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'auth-token': localStorage.getItem('auth-token')
    });
    const options = { headers };

    return this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/pm/devices?pa_id=${this.pm_id}`, options);
  }
```

What I am then doing, is adding the devices I receive from this request to a localStorage called devices in the component that I am using it for. This component appears on the home page on the initial load. The function looks like this:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.deviceService.getAllDevices().subscribe(data => {
      let temp_devices = [];
      data['devices'].forEach(device => {
        device.supported_memory.forEach(memory => {
          var o = Object.assign({}, device);
          var model_manufacturer = device.manufacturer + " " + device.model + " " + memory;
          var phone_image = device.manufacturer + " " + device.model;
            
          phone_image = phone_image.replace(/\s/g, '');
  
          o.phone_image = phone_image.toLowerCase();
    
          o.model_manufacturer = model_manufacturer;
          o.memory = memory;

          temp_devices.push(o);
        });
      });
      this.devices = temp_devices;

      this.devices = temp_devices.map(function(el, i, array){
        var o = Object.assign({}, el);
  
        return o;
      });

      localStorage.setItem('devices', JSON.stringify(this.devices));
    });
  }
```

As mentioned above, I don't understand why the request is not being called on the initial load, but gets called on the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `this.authenticationService.login(this.username, this.password);` is asynchronous. So first time loading the page when you call getAllDevices the token is not available. You can confirm it by inpecting devTools console.

```
 getAllDevices(){
    this.authenticationService.login(this.username, this.password);
    // rest code will continue to execute but token will be null
  }
```

Second time loading page, you dont see the problem because token already exist on local storage.

Solution:
you should call getAllDevices when token is already available.

Comment: It was right under my nose, but I didn't realise it. Thank you.